# Am I designing this WCF RESTful interface correctly?

Tags: wcf, api, rest, restful-authentication

I am creating a WCF webservice with WcF Authentication Service and the first set of functions I need is to manage an inbox for a client. The client will be determined by the authentication.

This is my attempt at a RESTful design of the API:

---

`https://api.mydomain.com/v1/inbox/messages (GET)`

Returns a page of results in the inbox with an optional search filter applied

- Count - number of records per page
- Page - page to start on
- Sort - (optional) field to sort on
- Search - (optional) text to search for

---

`https://api.mydomain.com/v1/inbox/mark (POST)`

Marks one or more messages read or unread

- Action - MarkRead or MarkUnread
- MessageIDs - list of Message IDs to mark

---

`https://api.mydomain.com/v1/inbox/archive (POST)`

Archives one or more messages

- MessageIDs - list of Message IDs to archive

---

Am I doing this right? If not, what would be a better way to design this interface?

Comment: Sounds like read and unread can be part of your second URL?

`https://api.mydomain.com/v1/inbox/mark/read` and `https://api.mydomain.com/v1/inbox/mark/unread`

Comment: Should they be two separate functions or one function with a parameter (which is more the norm in RESTful API)?

Comment: if you do what I suggested then it would be two end points right?  as in two URLs. But the system can handle them with the same method.

Comment: Okay, thanks... is it better to have two end points (one for every action)? Should they be POST if they change data? Is the rest correct?

Comment: If they change data they should be POST or PUT. Here is a link on comparison when to use which http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest and http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/put-or-post-the-rest-of-the-story/

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler has a [good summary](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) of the Richardson Maturity Model and what it takes to make a RESTful service.  Jan referenced one of Roy Fielding's posts, but there are some steps to take care of in addition to hypermedia (and [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)).

With reference to the [Richardson model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html), I think your API would need some changes to get to "Level 3" (duh duh duhhhh).  The `/v1/inbox/messages` collection looks sound, and only supporting `GET` indicates that it's a read-only resource to the user.  However `POST`ing actions and IDs to the `/v1/inbox/mark` and `/v1/inbox/archive` is only tunneling RPC-style services over HTTP - "Level 0" in the [article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

I'd suggest something like the following as being a naive, non-hypermedia (i.e. "Level 2") API:

- To retrieve a list of summary information of all of the messages (in all folders):

  ```
  GET /v1/messages HTTP/1.1
  Host: api.mydomain.com
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  content-type: text/xml

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <messages>
    <message subject="Subject" unread="true" id="1234" folder="inbox" />
    <message subject="Hello, world" unread="false" id="24" folder="inbox" />
    ...
  </messages>
  ```
- To retrieve a full message:

  ```
  GET /v1/messages/1234 HTTP/1.1
  Host: api.mydomain.com
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  content-type: text/xml

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <message subject="Subject" unread="true" id="1234" folder="inbox">
    Hi, this is the message.
  </message>
  ```
- To edit a message (e.g. to mark it as read and move it to the archive folder):

  ```
  POST /v1/inbox/messages/1234 HTTP/1.1
  Host: api.mydomain.com
  content-type: text/xml

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <message id="1234" unread="false" folder="archive" />
  ```

  Note: here I'm intentionally using `POST` instead of `PUT` to indicate a partial update.

Other things that stand out as needing attention are:

- Hypermedia responses and media types.  Frankly this is better explained by others (e.g. the [REST In Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805829) book, or the [InfoQ Coffee Cup example](http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow) by the same authors), but in short your responses should indicate to the client what other actions might be possible from the response to their most recent request, and allow them to discover the entire API from just a single URI.  As an example, there is an implication of folders collections above.  If `GET /v1/messages/1234` returned:

  ```
  <message subject="Subject" unread="true" id="1234" folder="inbox" >
    Message text here.

    <link rel="folder" href="http://api.mydomain.com/v1/folders/inbox" />
  </message>
  ```

  then the client would have a concrete example of a URI to try an `OPTIONS` on, and a good idea of what might be there.
- Response codes and content: `200 OK` is obvious. Respond with `403 Forbidden` if the user is not authorized to view a particular message, `404 Not Found` if the message ID doesn't exist.  Every time you return an error, give the client some indication of how to correct their request (if at all possible).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to read/unread part
I do not think you need a post. I think you need put method 
https://api.mydomain.com/v1/inbox/messageId/Read
https://api.mydomain.com/v1/inbox/messageId/Unread

Post needed when creating a new record and you want to update

For archive part I am agree. Just remember to return result for the archiving process.

Answer (score 0):

Roy's POST is helpful when facing such questions: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Hence: focus on defining media type(s) instead of coupling your clients to predefined sets of URIs. They need not be registered, to be useful, BTW.

Maybe also see http://www.nordsc.com/ext/classification_of_http_based_apis.html#http-type-one